# how to apply CSS / HTML in twitter API JSON results

Tags: php, twitter

using below code, TWITTER API and PHP, i have successfully fetch/get my twitter timeline.

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=twitter';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

my concern is, the **data/results** displayed fills up my whole window screen with text. im not sure how to apply CSS or HTML on it.

```
[{"created_at":"Sun Dec 09 05:21:29 +0000 2012","id":2232376342522313442,"id_str":"277231523253442","text":"http:\/\/t.co\/ro74jh4","source":"web","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"
```

the tutorial im following didn't mentioned how to arrange the fetched data.

Comment: Look up templating engines, though you can always write some HTML template yourself then loop over the received array and `sprintf` its data into the template.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to parse the JSON data that you got from object from Twitter.  Here is an example. You can use the array syntax to find which values you want to look up.

```
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();

$obj = json_decode($response, true);             


echo "<div><ul>";
foreach ($obj["statuses"] as $index => $result) {

$tweet = $result['text'];
$user = $result['user']['screen_name'];
$profile_image = $result['user']['profile_image_url'];

echo "<li>";
echo "<img src=\"".$profile_image."\" width=\"25px\" height=\"25px\" />";
echo "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$user\">@$user</a>";
echo " $tweet";
    echo "</li>";
} 

echo "</ul></div>";
```